# Windows Xp DNS Resolution not working

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, dns, hosts

Starting off, I am working on a client computer. I was removing a FBI MoneyPack Ransomware virus from a windows xp system. Well I got rid of that and then had a problem with the firewall. I did the whole resetting the firewall steps so that I could even use it. Here is a list of everything I have tried so far. (Been working on this computer since noon today.)

https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=fix+windows+xp+internet+host+file
https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=6653#xp
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034

also I tried these steps from other similar issues solved on this site.

[Windows XP Internet Issue](https://superuser.com/questions/313524/windows-xp-internet-issue)

[Are my connectivity issues on Windows XP related to DNS issues?](https://superuser.com/questions/367376/are-my-connectivity-issues-on-windows-xp-related-to-dns-issues)

[Why is 'ping' unable to resolve a name when 'nslookup' works fine?](https://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine)

Ok I am dealing with a Wired Ethernet connection and am 100% sure it is nothing outside the computer system I am working on. Funny thing is the internet on this computer was working before I removed the virus but was very slow and sometimes just quit loading pages, after that I found out that the firewall service was hijacked by the virus so I reset the firewall. Now I am having this issue. I can ping the router but when I ping google it quits. here is a cmd log of some steps and ipconfig status.

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Compaq_Owner>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : your-d0f670b45a
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-F2-EA-E7-15
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, October 31, 2014 7:09:03 PM
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, November 01, 2014 7:09:03
PM

C:\Documents and Settings\Compaq_Owner>netstat

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    your-d0f670b45a:1031   localhost:1032         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    your-d0f670b45a:1032   localhost:1031         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    your-d0f670b45a:1033   ord08s08-in-f0.1e100.net:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    your-d0f670b45a:1034   ord08s08-in-f4.1e100.net:http  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    your-d0f670b45a:1035   ord08s09-in-f0.1e100.net:https  ESTABLISHED

C:\Documents and Settings\Compaq_Owner>ping www.google.com
Ping request could not find host www.google.com. Please check the name and try a
gain.

C:\Documents and Settings\Compaq_Owner>
```

Any Help is Great right now. I was thinking Host file but it is untouched and original and setting up a static ip to my router didn't work.

Update: I just wanted to add that I have just noticed that applications like Java Update use the internet just fine, and I was able to verify this using task manager to check that it was using a internet connection. This means that is is a Browser issue or close. I feel like I have dealt with this before but I can't remember what was done to fix it.

Comment: also if I ping a google ip it comes up as destination host unreachable.

Comment: Also I can see it as an attached device in my router via my laptop so it is not a hardware issue.

Comment: Set DNS Servers manually to ones obtained from your ISP, or choose one of public DNS services like [OpenDNS and Google DNS](http://www.labnol.org/software/compare-dns-server-speed/18988/)

Comment: already tried that. set it to the public google dns server and also tried static everything with my router. keep in mind i will need this to automatically obtain this stuff when the client picks the computer back up. I do have a couple things but if all else fails ill restore to when it was virus infected and try again, as a last hope.

Comment: the odd thing is that it was working when the virus was still active, I could kill a process and have internet. It wasn't until I realized that the firewall was hijacked and did a cmd reset on that and it just quit working. before that happened the internet settings were set to use system proxy which was odd.

Comment: I just tried setting it up as a static ip again using ip range from my router and dns settings from the router to no success. With automatic settings I can ping 8.8.8.8 via cmd. Also applications like Java update will connect fine and update.

Comment: I can install a Different network card and the internet works fine so I will next uninstall the onboard driver and let windows reinstall that and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. After trying everything under the sun here is a good steps to try.

What eventually fixed it for me was:
1.) Right Click Computer
2.) Click on Manage
3.) Click on Device Manager
4.) Uninstall the internal network adapter driver.
5.) Restart 
6.) let windows reinstall it and it worked.

I am guessing it maybe got a corrupt file that deals with the dns service.

If the above does not work Try the links in the original question and lastly try this link http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-623990-can-t-dns-resolve-in-xp

Comment: That was the plan when I posted the question but it says I have to wait until tomorrow to accept the answer. "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" thanks.